# Creating Word document from Excel through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Folks. I have an Excel file and want to create a Word document with the data in a sheet. The program shows an error and I can't find the reason.

I tried to use the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' Objetos Word
  Dim obj1 As New Application
  Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

' Objetos Excel
  Dim wbBook As Workbook
  Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

  Dim Caminho, Arquivo, Nome_aluno, Ender As String
  Dim Gen_p, Gen_a, Hora, Prof, Resp As String
  Dim i, Comp As Integer
  Dim Coord_C As Integer
  Dim Coord_L As Integer
  Caminho = "D:\Data\Office\Excel\"
  Arquivo = "Anexo D - Ata de defesa TCC.docx"
```

The code continues, but is irrelevant for now.
The point is when I run the code I get the message:

> User defined type not defined

This is weird, because in another Excel file I can run it, and it works fine.
What have I missed? Do I have to link something?

Comment: Which line triggers the error? The rest of the code may, indeed, be relevant because you don't show anything connected with Word... My first thought would be that you haven't set a reference to the Word object library in Tools/References, so Excel doesn't recognize `Word.Document`. If you substitute `Object` things might work.

Comment: Hi, Cindy. The error is exactly in the line   Word.Document. I think you are right.  Where can I find the References you mention? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

To create a new Word doc from another application, add this...

```
Dim appWD As Word.Application 

Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
appWD.Documents.Add
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/working-with-other-applications/controlling-one-microsoft-office-application-from-another

Answer (score -1):

since your code uses:

```
Dim obj1 As New Application
```

You *must* set a VBA reference to whatever application (Word?) obj1 relates to. That is done via Tools|References. You *must* also tell VBA what application that is. For example:

```
Dim obj1 As New Word.Application
```

Comment: You shouldn't recommend `As New Word.Application` as that immediately instantiates the application. `Dim as Word.Application`  should always be used in conjunction with a `Set` line for the instantiation.

Comment: Sometimes, instantiating the application from the outset is quite appropriate. Regardless, the real issues here are both the lack of an application name and the  apparent lack of a VBA reference.

Comment: Cindy, Jenn and Macropod. I found my mistake. Really I needed to set a reference to Word documents. I did and it worked.

Comment: Tahn you all. :-)